# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in php

Tags: php

I am getting this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}'` when printing $html.

This is my code:

```
$html= while($rowe=$rese->fetch_array())
             { ;
$html .='<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:0;">
          <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
            <label style="font-weight:bold">Summary</label>
            <p>';
            $html .=ucfirst($rowe['summary']);
            $html .='</p>
            </div>
            </div><hr>';
            $html .= } ;
```

Comment: `$html .= } ;` does not have any sense as you are closing the `while` statement block while trying to append something to the string

Comment: @DonCallisto then how to close while loop

Comment: @user3770112: without appending anything to `html`; just put `}` Moreover you don't need all those `;` after `{` and `}`

Comment: @AhmedGinani you must have been confused me with OP :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/6521116)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this : `$html .= } ;`

```
$html = "";
while($rowe=$rese->fetch_array())
             { 
$html .='<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:0;">
          <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
            <label style="font-weight:bold">Summary</label>
            <p>';
            $html .=ucfirst($rowe['summary']);
            $html .='</p>
            </div>
            </div><hr>';
             }
```

Comment: `$html= while($rowe=$rese->fetch_array())` is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Bind only html in your variable:

```
while($rowe=$rese->fetch_array())
{ 
            $html ='<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:0;"><div class="col-md-12 form-group"><label style="font-weight:bold">Summary</label><p>';
            $html .=ucfirst($rowe['summary']);
            $html .='</p>
            </div>
            </div><hr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors ,
correct way is

```
while($rowe=$rese->fetch_array()) {
            $html .= '<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:0;"><div class="col-md-12 form-group"><label style="font-weight:bold">Summary</label><p>'.ucfirst($rowe["summary"]).'</p></div></div><hr>';
        }
```